# Order of fields in Django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using Django to execute some scripts in server-side and I'm using forms to get parameters.

I define my forms in the order I need those parameters and it renders it in that order. The problem is that when I submit the form it is sent without that order so the scripts execute something like:

./script parameter3 parameter1 parameter2

instead of

./script parameter1 parameter2 parameter3

each form has different fields and I only have one method to execute them all. So I take all the fields except csrftoken and so this way:

```
for arg in request.POST:
 args.append(request.POST.get(arg))
```

And executing then using

```
command.extend(args)
```

I have tried to define the order in the forms.py with

```
 self.fields.keyOrder = ['parameter1','parameter2','parameter3']
```

But I think its only for ordering when render. Is there anyway to control the order the submit send the data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `request.POST` is a dictionary, and does not have order.

Comment: In an order suggests you are trying to reference them by their array index which is rarely the best idea, why not include the parameters as a dictionary?

Comment: How I could do that? I can't get what you mean @Sayse

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Actually, `request.POST` is a `QueryDict` which is a subclass of `MultiValueDict` which is a subclass of `dict`. While the key order is not preserved, the multi-value part is ordered. So if you're storing everything sing the same key it will stay sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order of fields, don't use form to post data.

Consider posting JSON with AJAX, and puting the fields in a list:

```
// You can compose such a JSON string by extracting the fields with jQuery
var field1_obj = {
  name:"field1",
  value: $("#field1").value()
}
var field2_obj = {
  name:"field2",
  value: $("#field2").value()
}
var payload = {data:[field1_obj, field2_obj]}
var payload_json = JSON.stringify(payload)
// JSON string
{data: [{name: "field1", value:"val1"}, {name: "field1", value:"val1"}]}
// Post it to server
$.post(url, payload_json ...)
```

On server side, it is pretty trivial to load the json string into a python dictionary:

```
import json
form = json.loads(request.body)
```